# Flutter: Combine 2 class objects

Tags: flutter, inheritance

I have 2 class variables, both are objects of `BoxDecoration` class.

```
var buttonDownOuter = BoxDecoration(
boxShadow: [
  BoxShadow(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(55, 84, 170, 0.1),
    blurRadius: 8, // has the effect of softening the shadow
    offset: Offset(
      6, // horizontal, move right 10
      6, // vertical, move down 10
    ),
  ),
  BoxShadow(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.69),
    blurRadius: 10, // has the effect of softening the shadow
    offset: Offset(
      -4, // horizontal, move right 10
      -4, // vertical, move down 10
    ),
  ),
],
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26),
);
```

and,

```
var baseBack = BoxDecoration(
gradient: LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    colors: [
  const Color(0xFFE2E8F0),
  const Color(0xFFD0D6DE),
]));
```

How can I combine these `buttonDownOuter` and `baseBack` to apply to a container's decoration?

Also, hypothetically, if those had conflicting inheritances, how can I combine them?

Comment: does arguments are gonna same ? i mean in baseBack you gonna have gradient only or argument can be changed?

Comment: `BoxDecoration.copyWith()`

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: buttonDownOuter.copyWith(baseBack)  try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all the decoration properties:

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            // box shadow here
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(55, 84, 170, 0.1),
                blurRadius: 8, // has the effect of softening the shadow
                offset: Offset(
                  6, // horizontal, move right 10
                  6, // vertical, move down 10
                ),
              ),
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.69),
                blurRadius: 10, // has the effect of softening the shadow
                offset: Offset(
                  -4, // horizontal, move right 10
                  -4, // vertical, move down 10
                ),
              ),
            ],
            // border radius here
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26),
            // gradient here
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                const Color(0xFFE2E8F0),
                const Color(0xFFD0D6DE),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Output :
[image: Output]

I hope this helps

Comment: I know this, but I want to know how to combine those styles as variables. This is because some elements have the same fill, but with different shadows. If I define a variable, I can modify the decoration at once. It's like a theme.